# Angular form control alias

Tags: angular

I would like to know if there is some way to give a form control an alias.

I need this because the backend's language is in english but the front is in spanish (variable's names and form control's names).

I need a way to map the name of some fields from the backend with the name of the controls.

**Front end**

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      usuario: ['', [Validators.required]],
      nombre: ['', [Validators.required]],
      apellido: ['', [Validators.required]],
      inicial: [''] })
```

**Backend**

```
data: {
user: "pedros",
name: "Pedro",
lastname: "Sanchez",
initial: "PS"
}
```

Comment: I would think this is only necessary when sending data to the service, correct? If so, you would only need to write a mapper for the form data in your service. Populating the fields from existing data in English shouldn't create a problem.

Comment: In fact is to take the correct action when the server respond with an error in some field. i would have to write it on my own